# Finding a constant which makes a Homogeneous ODE into a Non-Homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have a Non-Homogeneous ODE of the form $y'' + 8y' + 17y = 5$  which I have obtained the solution $y(x) = ae^{-4x}[\cos(x) + i\sin(x)] + be^{-4x}[\cos(x)-i\sin(x)] + \frac{5}{17}$ where $a$ and $b$ are complex constants.

I am unsure of how to find a constant, $c$, which satisfies the equation $z(x) = y(x) - c$  where $c$ is a real constant and $z(x)$ is a Homogeneous Differential Equation. I originally thought that $c = \frac{5}{17}$ but that seems too simple.

How should I go about finding $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'' + 8y' + 17y = 5$$
$$y'' + 8y' + 17y - 5=0$$
$$y'' + 8y' + 17(y-\dfrac 5 {17}) = 0$$
Since $(y-\dfrac 5{17})'=y'$:
$$(y-\dfrac 5 {17})'' + 8(y-\dfrac 5 {17})' + 17(y-\dfrac 5 {17}) = 0$$
$$z'' + 8z' + 17z = 0$$
Where $z=y-\dfrac 5 {17}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $c=\frac{5}{17}$, which gives the particular solution to be $y_{p}(x)=\frac{5}{17}$.

Since the RHS is a constant, you would try a constant as your particular solution $y_{p}(x)=c$ and substituting gives $c=\frac{5}{17}$. See [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx).

Note your solution can be simplified further, since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants we can write
$$y(x) = c_{1}e^{-4x}\cos(x)+c_2e^{-4x}\sin(x) + \frac{5}{17}$$

where $c_1=a+b$ and $c_2=i(a-b)$.